# Балаклава — что это?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Что объединяет населенный пункт **Балаклава** в Севастополе и "головной убор" с таким же названием?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Их объединяет Крымская война в XIX веке. Англичане при осаде Севастополя замерзали и, чтобы защитить лицо от ветра и стужи, надевали такие вот шапочки, названные ими в честь занятого поселения. Ирония заключается в том, что в России это английское слово стало популярным незадолго до присоединения Крыма уже в веке XXI.

Comment: Я думаю, что Ваш ответ нуждается в серьезной правке. Сама — не смею.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова зря. Я на этот форум и пришёл, чтобы улучшить свою грамотность. В моих ответах, особенно старых, полно различных ошибок и я буду рад, если их исправят.

Comment: Однажды мне сделали замечание, что модераторский текст править не принято. Поэтому я и не решилась.

Comment: Я свои разрешаю, если при этом не меняется смысл. К тому же в 2014 г, я ещё не был модератором.